# How to fill the boxes with the digits 1 to 9 without any repetition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have found the answer $17\cdot4=68+25=93$ by trial and error. But my question is that- can we solve it applying any logic(without trial and error)???[image]

Comment: Logic can be used to reduce the amount of "trial and error" but I don't know how one can avoid considering "cases" entirely.

Comment: As said by @hardmath, logic can definitely help but I don't think it can completely solve the puzzle.

Comment: Can it be proved that it has a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

### There are no other solutions.

One way to think about searching for solutions is by imagining a decision tree, in which we "try" to assign digits $1$ through $9$ to the nine places shown in the calculation:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
  & A & B \\ 
\times &   & C \\
\hline
  & D & E \\
+ & F & G \\
\hline
  & H & I \end{array} $$

so that (to be a bit formal) we have these equal sets:

$$ \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} $$

Not all ways to organize such a search are equally efficient. A rather silly approach would be to generate a permutation of the nine digits and then check to see if the corresponding assignment to places gives a valid calculation.  Such a decision tree would have $9! = 362,880$ leaves to check.  Of course one might get lucky and find a solution before all $9!$ possible assignments are checked, but if you want to find *all* solutions, the entire tree has to be checked.

Logic helps us to organize a more efficient decision tree.  For example, we can argue a priori that not every digit is a valid choice for each place.  Note that $C=1$ is not possible because it would entail that $B=E$, and likewise $B=1$ is not admissible because we then would get $C=E$. A little further thought shows us that $D=1$ and $H=1$ are also impossible (since $C\gt 1$).  Thus $1$ can only be assigned to one of these five places, $A,E,F,G,I$.

Similarly $5$ can only be assigned to five places, $D,F,G,H,I$.  Since $C\gt 1$, we cannot let $A=5$ because the resulting product would have more than two digits.  More obviously $B,C,E$ cannot be $5$ because the multiplication would either entail a duplicate $5$ digit or a zero digit (which is not allowed).

We can also "prune" our decision tree dynamically by the order in which places are chosen to assign digits.  Some places' choices will restrict the remaining choices more than others, and so it is desirable to fix those assignments earlier in the decision tree.  As I wrote in [an older StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006568/487781) about cryptarithmetic puzzles,

> My advice is "fail early, fail often". That is, push as many checks for failure as early as possible into the assignment steps, thus pruning the search tree.

In the present problem this suggests choosing $C$ first.  We have eliminated $1$ and $5$ as possible values for $C$, leaving only seven possibilities, and once $C$ is chosen the remaining entries are sharply restricted: $10D+E = C(10A+B)$ and once values $A$ through $E$ are fixed, it will be quick to check if the four leftover digits can be arranged to form the final sum $10H+I = (10D+E)+(10F+G)$.

Before we consider the cases for $C$, let's show that $10D+E$ is at most $84$.  The reason is that $10H+I$ is at most $98$ and $10F+G$ at least $12$, so that their difference $10D+E$ is at most $86$.  But $86$ is not possible because it would require that digit $8$ is repeated, nor is $85$ possible because $E\neq 5$. Hence $10D+E \le 84$.

This will give considerable restriction on $10A+B = (10D+E)/C$, especially as we take the larger cases for $C$.  For specifically $C=2$ we have then $10A+B \le 42$, and combining this with the previous exclusions on placing the digits $1,5$, we have only these possibilities for product $(10A+B)*C$:

$$ \begin{align*}
13\times 2 &= 26 \text{ (digit 2 repeated)}\\
14\times 2 &= 28 \text{ (digit 2 repeated)}\\
16\times 2 &= 32 \text{ (digit 2 repeated)}\\
17\times 2 &= 34 \\
18\times 2 &= 36 \\
19\times 2 &= 38 \\
34\times 2 &= 68 \\
36\times 2 &= 72 \text{ (digit 2 repeated)}\\
37\times 2 &= 74 \text{ (digit 7 repeated)}\\
38\times 2 &= 76 \\
39\times 2 &= 78 
\end{align*} $$

After eliminating those cases noted above that entail a repeated digit, we have only six that allow $C=2$.  A similar consideration of cases $C=3,4,6,7$ can be made (NB: cases $C=8,9$ would exceed $10D+E \le 84$), and after dropping those with repeated digits we are left with only these seventeen possibilities for the product:

$$ \begin{align*}
17\times 2 &= 34 (98-56 = 42 > 34)\\
18\times 2 &= 36 (97-45 = 52 > 36)\\
19\times 2 &= 38 (76-45 = 31 < 38)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
34\times 2 &= 68 (97-15 = 82 > 68)\\
38\times 2 &= 76 (95-14 = 81 > 76)\\
39\times 2 &= 78 (65-14 = 51 < 78)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
16\times 3 &= 48 (97-25 = 72 > 48)\\
18\times 3 &= 54 (97-26 = 71 > 54)\\
19\times 3 &= 57 (86-24 = 62 > 57)\\
26\times 3 &= 78 (95-14 = 81 > 78)\\
27\times 3 &= 81 (96-45 = 51 < 81)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
13\times 4 &= 52 (98-67 = 31 < 52)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
17\times 4 &= 68 (95-23 = 72 > 68)\\
18\times 4 &= 72 (96-35 = 61 < 72)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
19\times 4 &= 76 (85-23 = 62 < 76)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
13\times 6 &= 78 (95-24 = 71 < 78)\;\textbf{not big enough}\\
12\times 7 &= 84 (96-35 = 61 < 84)\;\textbf{not big enough}
\end{align*} $$

We can quickly dispatch many of these possibilities by checking if the leftover digits will allow us to construct a difference $(10H+I)-(10F+G)$ at least as large as the product.  For the Readers' convenience we have in each case noted above the largest possible difference (take the largest two digits and subtract the smallest two digits).  Dropping those cases where this is **not big enough**, we are left with only nine that bear closer analysis.

We illustrate this last step with three examples.  When the product is $17\times 2 = 34$ then the leftover digits are $5,6,8,9$.  To make the final sum add up, we need in the units place to add $4$ to one of those leftover digits and get another one of them.  Here there is only one such sum, namely $4+5 = 9$.  But we cannot make the tens place work out, since $34+65\neq 89$.

Take another product $16\times 3 = 48$ and its leftover digits $2,5,7,9$. There are then two ways to make the units place sum up, either $8+7=15$ or $8+9=17$.  But $48+27\neq 95$ and $48+29\neq 57$, so we are unable to make the tens place work out.

The same failure occurs with all the other cases $C=2,3$.  Our last hope is the product $17\times 4 = 68$, with leftover digits $2,3,5,9$.  As already noted in the Question, this gives a solution $68+25=93$.  A posteriori that is the only solution possible.